# How to write Bean Shell Script to compare two variables and print the output. JMETER

Tags: if-statement, jmeter, comparison, beanshell

I have two variable 1)Expected(taken from excel file) & 2)Actual(regex from result)
Now i tried to compare both the variables using bean Shell Post processor Scripting.

```
if(("${Expected}").equals("${Actual}"))
{
IsSuccess = true;
}
else
{
IsSuccess = false;
}
```

which should actually mark sample as pass and fail according to the comparison.
But i can't find the sampler marked fail when the comparison returns false.
Is their any error in my condition.
Also Please help to print output to console
Help is appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't inline [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into a Beanshell (or any other) script, they might resolve into something which will cause compilation failure
2. If you want to mark sampler as passed or failed from the [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) you should be doing it a little bit differently

Example suggested code:

```
if (vars.get("Expected").equals(vars.get("Actual"))) {
    prev.setSuccessful(true);
}
else {
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

Other recommendations:

1. Going forward consider switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language as [Groovy performance is much higher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for any scripting implementations
2. You can achieve the same without having to write a single line of code via "normal" Response Assertion, example configuration would be something like:

   [image: JMeter Assertion Compare 2 Variables]

   See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally passing/failing your JMeter samplers using assertions.

Comment: Thank You @Dimitri T. I tried using response Assertion. Its working. I found it more simple